# Cannot Build and Install Html App using Web Works 2.1 on Device

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I'm new in BB Development and I want to test my application on Z3 Device ...

1. I installed WebWorks 2.1
2. Then request the bbidtoken.csk file, and I created author.p12 using WebWorks UI.
3. I enabled Developer Mode on Device.
4. Also I generated debug token debugtoken.bar using Command line tool.
5. I deployed debugtoken.bar on my Z3 device.
6. All files author.p12, barsigner.db, bbidtoken.csk, debugtoken.bar in this path:
   "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Research In Motion"
7. I created Project using WebWorks UI and by default its located in   "C:\Users\user1\WebWorks Projects\Project1"
8. I tried to Build my "Project1" app from WebWorks UI, but this error comes to me:

   [INFO]    Populating application source
   [INFO]    Parsing config.xml
   [INFO]    Generating output files
   [INFO]    **Error: Debug token does not exist or not a file**
   [INFO]    **Error: Debug token does not exist or not a file**
   [ERROR]   **Native Packager exception occurred**
   [ERROR]   **Native Packager exception occurred**

   An error has occurred

What did I forget to do????!?!

Comment: Did you correctly put path to your debug token? I think you have to write whole path to it

Comment: thank you @BojanKogoj .. Maybe I need some baby steps from you :) Since I'm totally new.
My Debug token in "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Research In Motion"
And my Application "C:\Users\user1\WebWorks Projects\Project1"
Where exactly should put the token?

Note: I'm using WebWorks 2.1 Web Page UI to Build and Install.

Comment: I can't help you much, I work with Cascades. Recheck token paths, that's all I can suggest. Maybe there are settings?

Comment: When I installed WebWorks, I cannot see bbwp.bat file! Is it be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Rename your debugtoken.bar to blackberry10debugtoken.bar and place it inside .cordova folder under %user% and build again. This is one time activity after this you can use BB10 Webworks web interface for direct building and installation of application.Please do not forget to mark it as answer if you got this as your solution :) 
I hope it helps!!!